# Unable to free char-pointer element of a struct when the string reaches a certain length

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, free

Below I have a struct defined to contain one element of type `char*`

```
struct TokenizerT_ {
    char * name;
};

typedef struct TokenizerT_ TokenizerT;
```

And when I create an instance of the struct `TokenizerT`, I allocate the memory needed for the struct and its element,

```
TokenizerT *TKCreate(char * ts) {
    TokenizerT *t= (TokenizerT *) malloc(sizeof(TokenizerT));
    t->name= (char *) malloc(sizeof(ts));
    strcpy(t->name,ts);
    return t;
}
```

In the main function, I take in a string through the command line using `scanf` and print out certain things that could perhaps help solve the issue,

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    TokenizerT *token;
    char input[50];
    scanf("%s",input);
    char *pin = input;
    token = TKCreate(pin);

    printf("The address of the tokenizer is %p\n", token);
    printf("The length of the name is %lu\n", strlen(token->name));
    printf("The address of the name is %p\n", token->name);
    printf("The size of the TokenizerT structure is %lu\n", sizeof(TokenizerT));
    printf("The name starting from character 27 is %s\n", token->name + 26);   
    pin=token->name;
    printf("The whole name is %s\n",pin);

    TKDestroy(token);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is being caused by my TKDestroy method in which I free the only member of the struct but I'm not sure why,

```
void TKDestroy( TokenizerT * tk ) {
    free(tk->name);
    //free(tk);
}
```

When running the program and inputting a string of length 26 or smaller, the program runs fine with no error.

[image]

But once I input a string longer than 26 characters, this happens

[image]
[image]

I know the error is being caused when I free the struct's char-pointer because I commented out the line where I freed the entire struct instance. Also, changing the size of the char array, `input`, seemed to have had no effect on the output. The error seems to only be occurring when I try to free a struct's char pointer that points to a string that has a length longer than 26. I've been told that it usually has to do with trying to free memory that's not allocated or is forbidden by access. However I am still able to access the memory addresses of the characters after the 26th character. Why is this the case?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(ts))` allocates memory for the size of the *pointer* `ts` not what it is pointing to.

Comment: The expression `sizeof(ts)` is equal to the size of a pointer (typically 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your platform). You probably want to use `strlen(ts)+1` instead.

Comment: @WeatherVane but then why does the length of the string affect the program's ability to free just the pointer?

Comment: @ChrisGong: The subsequent problem is memory override, which yields undefined behavior. Generally speaking, anything could happen. In practice, you are overriding the meta-data which is later used by the `free` function.

Comment: @ChrisGong because if you have already written outside of the allocated memory, expecting it to be enough, you'll then have *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @barakmanos Excuse me if I sound naive but since I was allocating only 8 bytes for the char pointer, how come I was still able to free up to 26 characters?

Comment: @ChrisGong: Again - although the problem occurs when you attempt to free the allocated memory block, the **source** of the problem is the fact that you write more than `sizeof(char*)` bytes of data into that block, thus leading the rest of your program to invoke undefined behavior during runtime (or as I said, more specifically, overriding meta-data used by the `free` function (though this is not something dictated by the C-language standard)).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try to remove the memory allocation for

```
       t->name
```

and change it to

```
     t->name=ts;
```

Also, you have to remove the command

```
    strcpy(t->name,ts);
```

because that job is performed by the previous command. Then it should give you
no errors.
As far as the TKDestroy(..) you can include the command you commented that is the

```
    free(tk);
```

Hope these help.